# Cannot construct instance of dataclass in SpringBootTest when specifying classes to use in annotation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5

I have a repository test in a spring boot project that I'm running into errors on and I can't figure it out.

And my repository test looks like this:

```kotlin
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@SpringBootTest(
    //classes = [
    //    AnimationRepository::class,
    //    TestDataSourceConfiguration::class,
    //    ObjectMapper::class,
    //]

)
class AnimationRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var namedParameterJdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

    @Autowired
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    private lateinit var animationRepository: AnimationRepository


    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        animationRepository = AnimationRepository(namedParameterJdbcTemplate, objectMapper)
    }

    @Test
    fun `saveAnimation - can save animation record successfully`() {
        val animation = Animation("a cool annimation", 1, 8, 8, 1, listOf(Frame(1, listOf(0xFFFFFF, 0xCCCCCC))))

        animationRepository.save(animation)

        val actual = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(
            """
            SELECT * FROM matrix_animator.animations
        """,
        ) { resultSet, _ ->
            val frames = resultSet.getString("frames")
            print(frames)
            val jsonnode = objectMapper.readTree(frames)
            print(jsonnode)
            val animation = Animation(
                resultSet.getString("title"),
                resultSet.getInt("user_id"),
                resultSet.getInt("height"),
                resultSet.getInt("width"),
                resultSet.getInt("speed"),
                objectMapper.readValue(resultSet.getString("frames"), object : TypeReference<List<Frame>>() {})
            )
            animation
        }.first()
        assertEquals(animation, actual)
    }
}
```

At the moment, the repository just inserts the animations into a postgres table. The `frames` data that is causing the tests to fail when we're trying to deserialize it for the assertion is stored as jsonb in the db:

```kotlin
@Repository
class AnimationRepository(
    private val template: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) {
    fun save(animation: Animation) {
        template.update(
            """
                INSERT INTO matrix_animator.animations
                (title, frames, user_id, height, width, speed)
                VALUES
                (:title, :frames::jsonb, :userId, :height, :width, :speed)
            """,
            MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("title", animation.title)
                .addValue("frames", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(animation.frames))
                .addValue("userId", animation.userId)
                .addValue("height", animation.height)
                .addValue("width", animation.width)
                .addValue("speed", animation.speed)
        )
    }

}
```

And my Frame dataclass looks like this:

```kotlin
data class Frame (
    val positionInAnimation: Int,
    val pixels: List<Int>
)
```

Back in the test class, note the commented out classes in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. When I run the test like this it passes fine:
[image]

But this is loading the entire application context to run a repository test, so I'd like to narrow down the classes pulled in to just what should be needed for the test. When I specify those classes in the annotation:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [
        AnimationRepository::class,
        TestDataSourceConfiguration::class,
        ObjectMapper::class,
    ]
)
```

My tests fail with the error:

> cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
> at [Source: (String)"[{"pixels": [16777215, 13421772], "positionInAnimation": 1}]"; line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
> [image]

In addition to my repository class I'm pulling in my custom ObjectMapper configuration from my `src` path:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return ObjectMapper()
            .findAndRegisterModules()
    }
}
```

And my test datasource configuration. I'm fitting in test containers and liquibase (first time setting it up on my own so it's roughed in) so I can test against an actual DB:

```kotlin
@Configuration("test-datasource-configuration")
@Profile("integration-test")
class TestDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean("test-postgres-datasource")
    fun testPostgresDataSource(): DataSource {
        val postgresContainer =
            PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:15-alpine")
                .withUsername("postgres")
                .withPassword("password")

        postgresContainer.start()

        val host = postgresContainer.host
        val port = postgresContainer.firstMappedPort

        val dataSource = DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .apply {
                driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                url("jdbc:postgresql://$host:$port/postgres")
                username("postgres")
                password("password")
            }
            .build()

        val changeLog = File("src/test/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml")
        // TODO: this works, but it's using deprecated tooling. figure out the current way of doing it
        val liquibase = Liquibase(
            changeLog.name,
            FileSystemResourceAccessor(changeLog.parentFile),
            DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(JdbcConnection(dataSource.connection))
        )
        liquibase.update(Contexts(), LabelExpression())

        return dataSource
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun namedParameterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("test-postgres-datasource") dataSource: DataSource): NamedParameterJdbcTemplate {
        return NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that because the test passes when I load the entire application context but fail when I specify the classes to use that this means I'm missing some part of the tooling needed to properly deserialize the `frames` json string into the list of frame objects, but I don't know what tool I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

:heavy-sigh: I figured it out. The snag was in my SpringBootTest configuration:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [
        AnimationRepository::class,
        TestDataSourceConfiguration::class,
        // ObjectMapper::class,
        JacksonConfiguration::class,
    ]
)
class AnimationRepositoryTest {
```

I was including ObjectMapper as part of the classes that should be loaded, but that's the bean that I wanted to use, the *class* that configures that bean is what needed to be included, specifically the JacksonConfiguration class that holds the bean definition.

[image]